# Changed property of usercontrol does not display changes

Tags: data-binding, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I have a universal (windows) app and have an `FlipView` control http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/windows/apps/hh850405.aspx

In my `MainPage` method I call a method which fills my FlipView:

```
foreach(var s in oc)
{
    var bla = new ProductSet(s.Product1, s.Product2, s.Product3);
    flipView.Items.Add(bla);
}
```

I also have subscribed to the `FlipView_SelectionChanged` to add more items after a while to try and get this lazy loading effect.

my `ProductSet` class is an usercontrol (ProductSet.xaml)

```
public sealed partial class ProductSet: UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Product Product1 { get; set; }
    public Product Product2 { get; set; }
    public Product Product3 { get; set; }

    public ProductSet()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ProductSet(Product p1, Product p2, Product p3)
    {
        Product1 = p1;
        Product2 = p2;
        Product3 = p3;

        DataContext = this;
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

When I change the current flipview item's `Product1` it does not display the change...

```
Product selectedProduct = (Product)gv.SelectedItem;
ProductSet ps = (NikkiSet)flipView.SelectedItem;
ps.Product1 = selectedProduct; // other object of class Product
```

My usercontrol has an image which I would like to change:

```
<Image Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding Product1.Picture}" Name="imgProduct1" />
```

But it does not change. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

You need to add some changes in your view model for rebind the property after its value changed. Use the below code.

```
public sealed partial class ProductSet : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Product product1;
    private Product product2;
    private Product product3;

    public Product Product1
    {
        get
        {
            return product1;
        }
        set
        {
            product1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Product1");
        }
    }
    public Product Product2
    {
        get
        {
            return product2;
        }
        set
        {
            product2 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Product2");
        }
    }
    public Product Product3
    {
        get
        {
            return product3;
        }
        set
        {
            product3 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Product3");
        }
    }

    public ProductSet()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ProductSet(Product p1, Product p2, Product p3)
    {
        Product1 = p1;
        Product2 = p2;
        Product3 = p3;

        DataContext = this;
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks! I needed the propfull snippet instead of prop and the `OnPropertyChanged` stuff of course!